# iOS is it possible to only use the largest size icon file?

Tags: ios

In iOS, can I only supply the largest icon file (1024x1024) and let the OS scale down the file for the rest of the required size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

iTunes Connect will not allow you to upload a binary to the App Store unless it contains all of the required App Icon sizes.

There are, however, some tools that make this easy to do in Sketch or from CLI.